# Postman Form Data to ASP.NET Core 2.2 Controller not binding to Command with private setters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

**Tools**

- Visual Studio 2017
- ASP.NET Core 2.2
- Postman v7.2.0

**What I'm trying to do**

Send FormData from Postman to an ASP.NET Core controller and have the data from the request bind to to a command class that has properties with private setters.

I've sent JSON data using the same setup (private setters) with no problem.  The `FromBody` attribute deserialises the JSON string to the model without errors.

**The Problem**

Properties that are primitive types do not bind if the model has a private setter.  However, complex types do regardless of the access modifier.

**Controller**

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateItemAsync([FromForm]CreateItemCommand command)
{
    bool result = false;

    commandResult = await _mediator.Send(command);

    if (!commandResult)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

**Command**

Note: The `Title` property has been left with a public setter deliberately to illustrate the behviour

```cs
[DataContract]
public class CreateItemCommand
    :IRequest<bool>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public HashSet<string> Tags { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ItemDate { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<IFormFile> Documents { get; private set; }

    public CreateItemCommand()
    {
        Skills = new HashSet<string>();
        Systems = new HashSet<string>();
    }

    public CreateItemCommand(string title, string description, 
        int count, HashSet<string> tags, string itemDate, 
        List<IFormFile> documents)
        : this()
    {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        Count = count
        Tags = tags;
        ItemDate = itemDate;
        Documents = documents;
    }
}
```

In Postman I now setup the request as follows:

[image]

I've had to obfuscate some of the information, but you can see that the primitive types with private setters are not set.

[image]

**Questions**

1. Why does the property access modifier only affect properties with primitive types?
2. Why does this happens when the parameter attribute is set to `FromForm` but not when it's set to `FromBody`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the property access modifier only affect properties with primitive types?

For Asp.Net Core ModelBinder, it will check whether the property is private access setter by [ComplexTypeModelBinder](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/8d66f104f7f2ca42ee8b21f75b0e2b3e1abe2e00/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/ComplexTypeModelBinder.cs) code below:

```
protected virtual object CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (bindingContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
    }

    // If model creator throws an exception, we want to propagate it back up the call stack, since the
    // application developer should know that this was an invalid type to try to bind to.
    if (_modelCreator == null)
    {
        // The following check causes the ComplexTypeModelBinder to NOT participate in binding structs as
        // reflection does not provide information about the implicit parameterless constructor for a struct.
        // This binder would eventually fail to construct an instance of the struct as the Linq's NewExpression
        // compile fails to construct it.
        var modelTypeInfo = bindingContext.ModelType.GetTypeInfo();
        if (modelTypeInfo.IsAbstract || modelTypeInfo.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) == null)
        {
            var metadata = bindingContext.ModelMetadata;
            switch (metadata.MetadataKind)
            {
                case ModelMetadataKind.Parameter:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        Resources.FormatComplexTypeModelBinder_NoParameterlessConstructor_ForParameter(
                            modelTypeInfo.FullName,
                            metadata.ParameterName));
                case ModelMetadataKind.Property:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        Resources.FormatComplexTypeModelBinder_NoParameterlessConstructor_ForProperty(
                            modelTypeInfo.FullName,
                            metadata.PropertyName,
                            bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.FullName));
                case ModelMetadataKind.Type:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        Resources.FormatComplexTypeModelBinder_NoParameterlessConstructor_ForType(
                            modelTypeInfo.FullName));
            }
        }

        _modelCreator = Expression
            .Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.New(bindingContext.ModelType))
            .Compile();
    }

    return _modelCreator();
}
```

> Why does this happens when the parameter attribute is set to FromForm but not when it's set to FromBody

For `FromBody`, it is used `JsonInputFormatter` to bind the model from the body request, it's used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserilize the object and `Newtonsoft.Json` support deserize the object which contains private setter from json string.